# Tkinter and sending StringVar through pipes

Tags: python, tkinter, pipe

I started to play with processes recently. To try out some stuff, I wrote a very simple GUI and thought about the following:

- There is a label, and a button
- A process will check if the button is clicked, then edit a label accordingly.

To do that, I tried to send a StringVar to another process through a pipe, edit it, then send it back. The relevant code is below:

```
def changeText(pipe1, pipe2, str):
    while 1:
        if pipe1[1].recv() == "a":
            print("received")
            str.set("clicked")
            pipe2[0].send(str)
        else:
            pass

def buttonClicked(pipe):
    pipe[0].send("a")

txt2go = tk.StringVar(master=root, value="not clicked")

btn1 = tk.Button(text = "go", command = lambda : buttonClicked(pipe1))
btn1.place(x=50, y=80)

proses1 = mp.Process(target=changeText, args=(pipe1, pipe2, txt2go))
proses1.start()
```

However the program gives the following output (even before I tried to receive the StringVar):

```
Process Process-1:
received
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in    _bootstrap
self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
     File "/home/cetin/PycharmProjects/Process_deneme_PC       /Process_deneme_pc.py", line 9, in changeText
       pipe2[0].send(str)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206,  in send
       self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
       cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
   _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_tkinter.tkapp'>: attribute lookup tkapp on _tkinter failed
```

What does it mean, and can you suggest any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass tkinter objects to other processes. In the case of `StringVar`, you can only send the value of the variable in the pipe (eg: `txt2go.get()`), not the variable itself (eg: `txt2go`).

Comment: so can anything be done to update the label content?  any workarounds?

Comment: @ÇetinKöktürk: the workaround is to pass the string value back and forth.

Comment: eh, how can passing it back and forth serve to this purpose? could you post a pseudocode at least?

Comment: @ÇetinKöktürk: I don't know what your real purpose is. You simply cannot pass tkinter objects through a pipe, and you cannot have another process directly configure tkinter objects.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the fact that I couldn't trigger the GUI to update itself. However, after some research, I discovered method `root.update()`, where `root` is a `Tk()` object. To trigger the changes, you must update the content with a `while 1:` loop, instead of using `mainloop()`.

Also, it seems like Python is making more use of queues instead of pipes. Asynchronous inter-process communication is hard with pipes, because the process is being blocked by the `.recv()` call until there is something to read. With queues, this problem can be overcome with `Queue` object option `block=False`.